# Lotus Notes appointment form

Tags: lotus-notes, alarms

can i modify the form that appears when an alarm remember me something ?

the form that i want to modify is this:

**http://lotusnotes.oit.unlv.edu/sites/default/files/lotusnotes/LN%20Reminders%20SS3.png**

In particular i want **to add another button** with some script inside.

Where i can find that form ?
I try to search it but i don't find anything

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.
This form is hardcoded in the client and cannot be modified.